# How would you code this? Should I use a loop or keep it how I have it coded?

Tags: python-2.7

I have this method for my NBA basketball game simulation. The method checks with a variable named self.quarterMins to tell if the minutes in the quarter are done. Then it changes the index for 2 different variables that I use in my code to tell what quarter is being played.

```
def checkQuarter(self):
    # Method that checks and makes sure that the quarter and game aren't over.
    self.quarterIndex = 0

    if self.quarterMins[0] > 0:
        self.quarterIndex = 0
        self.playerMins = -4
    elif self.quarterMins[1] > 0:
        self.quarterIndex = 1
        self.playerMins = -3
    elif self.quarterMins[2] > 0:
        self.quarterIndex = 2
        self.playerMins = -2
    elif self.quarterMins[3] > 0:
        self.quarterIndex = 3
        self.playerMins = -1
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Umm... what is `self.quarterMins` - looks like it's supposed to be a list of length 4? And `self.playerMins` - is that supposed to be a way to index into that list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method would do the same:

```
def checkQuarter(self):
    self.quarterIndex = 0
    for i in xrange(4):
        if self.quarterMins[i] > 0:
            self.quarterIndex = i
            self.playerMins = -4 + i
            break
    else:
        return False
```

This uses a loop to let the variable `i` go from 0 to 3 and it'll set the `self.quarterIndex` and `self.playMins` variables whenever the if statement is true. When that's the case, it'll break out of the for loop using `break` and the method is done. If it doesn't happen at all then Python will run the `else:` section that's part of the for loop - that will only run when you don't use `break` in the for loop.

I'm not necessarily saying the above code is better but it does shorten the logic. You can also write it like this (but I'm also not sure whether that's better):

```
def checkQuarter(self):
    self.quarterIndex = 0
    index = None
    for i in xrange(4):
        if self.quarterMins[i] > 0:
            index = i
            break
    if index is None:
        return False
    self.quarterIndex = index
    self.playerMins = -4 + index
```

Comment: Awesome! I couldn't quite figure out a better way... This works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I probably would have getters for `quarterIndex()` and `playerMins()` and don't store any values for those variables. Then you don't need to implement `checkQuarter()` to update variables. I find that this method would have the potential to introduce bugs if it doesn't get called the right time.

I would also reverse checking the `quarterMins`, because then your code assumes to use always the highest quarter, even if the other quarters still have values > 0.

```
def quarterIndex():
    for i in range(4,-1,-1):
        if self.quarterMins[i] > 0:
            return i
    return None

def playerMins():
    quarterIndex = quarterIndex()
    if (quarterIndex != None):
         return -4 + quarterIndex
    return None

def gameIsRunning():
    if (quarterIndex() != None):
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: I incorporated Simeon's idea of using a for loop and calculating playerMins based on the quarterIndex. Also added another method for checking if the game is running

Answer (score 0):

I do this (you can use range too)

```
def checkQuarter(self):
    self.quarterIndex = 0

    for i, item in enumerate(self.quarterMins):
        if item > 0:
            self.quarterIndex = i
            self.playerMins = i - 4
    if self.quarterIndex == 0:
        return False
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to the given code: you need to `return False` only when the first four values in `self.quarterMins` are 0 or less. In your code that won't happen because you'll return `False` right away when the first one is 0 or less.

Comment: @Simeon Visser You're right I had a copy and paste error, hold on I'll edit it